# Problem with definition of renewal process.

Tags: stochastic-processes, renewal-processes

So I have to prove the following excercise:

Let $N(t)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \mathbb{1}_{\{J_n\leq t\}}$ where $J_n=\sum_{k=1}^n X_i$
where the $X_i$ are positive i.i.d. random variables.

Let $\{N(t),t>0\}$ be a renewal process, prove the followings equalities
\begin{equation*}
    1=\lim_{t\xrightarrow{}\infty}\mathbb{P}\left[N(t)>n\right]=\mathbb{P}\left[\lim_{t\xrightarrow{}\infty}N(t)>n\right],
\end{equation*}
so we can conclude that, $\mathbb{P}\left[\lim_{t\xrightarrow{}\infty}N(t)=\infty\right]=1$.

My problem is with the definition of Renewal Process. I claim that the above will be false if the $X_i$ aren't finite almost surely.

Comment: In probability theory the term random variable is generally used for measurable functions with values in $\mathbb R$. $\pm \infty$ are not  permissible values of $X_i$.

Comment: But why is it permissible for $N(t)$?

Comment: $N(t)$ is an extended real valued measurable function. We should not call it a random variable unless we know it is finite.